# how to map data with headers in pandas when there are no fixed headers

Tags: python, pandas

I have pre defined headers for my data frame . but data we receive might or might not include all the columns . however our output file should have all the fields from header. If there is no data in the input file, then keep it blank else populate the values.

```
input file 1:
ID  Name   Address    Shippment
1   john   address1   Y
2   Jessy  address2   N

input file2 
ID  Name   Address    Shippment   Delivered
1   john   address1   Y            Y
2   Jessy  address2   N            N

headers=['ID','Name','Address','Shippment','Delivered']

output file 1:
    ID  Name   Address    Shippment   Delivered
    1   john   address1   Y            
    2   Jessy  address2   N   

 output file 1:
ID  Name   Address    Shippment   Delivered
1   john   address1   Y            Y
2   Jessy  address2   N            N
```

how do I map the headers to the soruce file when the headers are random?

I tried using zip and update but this looks at index and map. The Source columns can be random and it has to match the fields order from the header.

```
        for i,index in  zip(header,df):
                final.update({i: df[index].tolist()})
        df_final= pd.DataFrame(final)
```

How can I acheive this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`reindex()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to ensure the pre-defined headers are all included. Any missing columns in the data will be populated with NaN:

```py
headers = ['ID','Name','Address','Shippment','Delivered']
df = df.reindex(columns=headers)
```

Input

```
   ID   Name   Address Shippment
0   1   john  address1         Y
1   2  jessy  address2         N
```

Output

```
   ID   Name   Address Shippment  Delivered
0   1   john  address1         Y        NaN
1   2  jessy  address2         N        NaN
```

If the columns in the input are not in the pre-defined sequence, `reindex()` will fix that as well:

Input

```
   ID   Address   Name Shippment
0   1  address1   john         Y
1   2  address2  jessy         N
```

Output

```
   ID   Name   Address Shippment  Delivered
0   1   john  address1         Y        NaN
1   2  jessy  address2         N        NaN
```